# Белый лист Android

Tags: android, service, whitelist

долго гугли как сделать не убиваемый сервис для push-уведомлений. В пример можно взять такие приложения как ВК, Instagram и т.д.

В итоге нагуглил, что сервис должен выглядеть вот так:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final int INTERVAL_CALL = 10;
    LastTimeHandler mLastTimeHandler;
    ThumbnailDownloader mThumbnailDownloader;

    private final IBinder mIBinder = new LocalBinder();

    private Handler mHandler = null;

    public static Intent newIntent(Context context) {
        return new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        Global.logUser(getApplicationContext());
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if(mThumbnailDownloader == null) {
            mThumbnailDownloader = new ThumbnailDownloader(getApplicationContext());
        }

        if(mLastTimeHandler == null) {
            mLastTimeHandler = new LastTimeHandler(getApplicationContext());
        }

        if(Global.hasConnection(this)) {
            if(mHandler != null) {
                mThumbnailDownloader.setHandler(mHandler);
            }
            mThumbnailDownloader.currentSales();
        }

        if(Global.hasConnection(MyService.this)) {
            Date date = new Date();

            SimpleDateFormat newDayFormatForDateNow = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
            String format = newDayFormatForDateNow.format(date);

            String date1 = SaveLoadClass.loadDate1(this);
            String date2 = SaveLoadClass.loadDate2(this);

            String ddate1 = changeTime(format, date1);
            String ddate2 = changeTime(format, date2);



            try {
                if(newDayFormatForDateNow.parse(ddate1).before(newDayFormatForDateNow.parse(ddate2))) {

                    if(newDayFormatForDateNow.parse(newDayFormatForDateNow.format(date)).after(newDayFormatForDateNow.parse(ddate1)) &&
                       newDayFormatForDateNow.parse(newDayFormatForDateNow.format(date)).before(newDayFormatForDateNow.parse(ddate2))) {
                        mLastTimeHandler.onlineUser();
                    } else {
                    }
                } else {



                    String ndate1  = changeTime(format, date1);
                    String ndate2  = changeTime(format, date2);
                    String new_day = changeTime(format, "00:00");

                    if(newDayFormatForDateNow.parse(newDayFormatForDateNow.format(date)).after(newDayFormatForDateNow.parse(new_day))) {
                        if(newDayFormatForDateNow.parse(newDayFormatForDateNow.format(date)).before(newDayFormatForDateNow.parse(ndate2))) {
                            Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                            calendar1.setTime(newDayFormatForDateNow.parse(ndate1));
                            calendar1.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                            ndate1 = newDayFormatForDateNow.format(calendar1.getTime());
                        }
                    }

                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.setTime(newDayFormatForDateNow.parse(ndate2));
                    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                    ndate2 = newDayFormatForDateNow.format(calendar.getTime());

                    if(newDayFormatForDateNow.parse(newDayFormatForDateNow.format(date)).after(newDayFormatForDateNow.parse(ndate1)) &&
                       newDayFormatForDateNow.parse(newDayFormatForDateNow.format(date)).before(newDayFormatForDateNow.parse(ndate2))) {
                        mLastTimeHandler.onlineUser();
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private String changeTime(String date, String time) {
        String temp = date.substring(0, 10);
        temp += " ";
        temp += time;

        return temp;
    }

    public static void setServiceAlarm(Context context, boolean isOn) {
        Intent i = MyService.newIntent(context);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        if(isOn) {
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), INTERVAL_CALL, pi);
        } else {
            alarmManager.cancel(pi);
            pi.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();

        if(mHandler != null)
        {
            mHandler = null;
        }

        // перезапуск сервиса
        setServiceAlarm(this, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        // перезапуск сервиса
        setServiceAlarm(this, true);
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mIBinder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder
    {
        public MyService getInstance()
        {
            return MyService.this;
        }
    }

    public void setHandler(Handler handler)
        mHandler = handler;
    }
}
```

Потом гугли в сторону белого листа и нагуглил вот это:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void WhiteList() {
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        //java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(Ljava/lang/String;)Z in class Landroid/os/PowerManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.os.PowerManager' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
        boolean inWhiteList = false;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            inWhiteList = powerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(getPackageName());
            if (!inWhiteList) {
                WhiteListDialogFragment whiteListDialogFragment = WhiteListDialogFragment.newInstance();
                whiteListDialogFragment.show(PrivateOfficeActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
            }
        }
    }
```

Я протестировал это на двух телефонах Samsung OS 7.0 и ZTE OS 7.0.
Дело в том, что на Samsung'е сервисы достаточно часто умирают, допустим после перезагрузки телефона или если полностью изолировать телефон от интернет сети и заново включить. А на ZTE очень часто предлагают программу 
добавить в белый список, как-будто после каждого закрытия он оттуда удаляется. Если кто сталкивался с данной проблемой буду рад помощи.

Как сделать так, чтобы приложение попало сюда автоматически?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) - свой сервис унаследуйте от FirebaseMessagingService
[один из примеров](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IlzcXlOatCo&vl=ru)

Comment: Так он всё время висит на виду у пользователя, я не думаю, что это мне подходит.

Comment: @СынБожий андроид специально уходит от "невидимых" пуш уведомлений, чтобы уменьшить риск слежки и т.д.
Для пуш-уведомлений можно использовать firebase

Comment: Я не правильно понял вопрос, думал вы говорите про сервис который нужен для push-уведомлений. Обновляю ответ